# I have sample code transposition Rail Fence encryption, but not encrypt after submit

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, encryption

I have sample code for the transposition Rail Fence encryption, but it does not encrypt after submit.

Function encrypt code:

```
Function Encrypt(ByVal rail As Integer, ByVal txtPlainText As String) As String
    Dim railFence As New List(Of String)()
    For i As Integer = 0 To rail - 1
        railFence.Add("")
    Next

    Dim number As Integer = 0
    Dim increment As Integer = 1
    For Each c As Char In txtPlainText
        If number + increment = rail Then
            increment = -1
        ElseIf number + increment = -1 Then
            increment = 1
        End If
        railFence(number) += c
        number += increment
    Next

    Dim buffer As String = ""
    For Each s As String In railFence
        buffer += s
    Next
    Return buffer
End Function
```

And coding submit :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim key As Integer = ""
    Dim txtPlainText As String = ""

    Dim cipherText As String = Encrypt(key, txtPlainText)

End Sub
```

coding not work for me. no error, but not encrypt plaintext.

Comment: The question is unclear. Be specific about what you expect and what actually happens.

Comment: coding not work for me . . .
not error, but not encrypt plaintext.
sorry, my English is not good

Comment: Is this the real code?  Because `Integer = ""` makes no sense, and then all it does is `Encrypt(key, "")`

Comment: sorry . . .
I am convert from c# to vb :(
please help fix . . .

Comment: It's still not clear if you have a problem in Encrypt() or in Button1_Click(). You will have to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: OK, thanks for help Mr. Henk :)

Source : http://times.imkrisna.com/2011/01/rail-fence-cipher-c-source-code-2/